# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation Forms authentication

Tags: forms-authentication, sharepoint-2010

I've followed through this(http://goo.gl/1LTX) guide to setup FBA in SP 2010, but I get an error...

Note: I have enable WCF error messages

Cannot get Membership Provider with name wss_fba. The membership provider for this process was not properly configured. You must configure the membership provider in the .config file for every SharePoint process.

Any ideas?

I've checked the config and the default for membership and roles is correct as I have setup in IIS 7.

```
<membership defaultProvider="wss_fba" />
<roleManager defaultProvider="wss_roles" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your own membership provider to the web.config file of the SecurityTokenServiceApplication. You can do that either by hand (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\SecurityToken) or by IIS manager (open up SharePoint Web Services and modify the providers in the SecurityTokenServiceApplication webapp).

Comment: perfect thanks...I did actually find out a while back, but this was the exact problem!!

Worth saying though, that even though I have made this change, the login still doesnt work...
I put in my username and password hit sign in, the page just refreshes and clears the text boxes?? weird??